# Wireless/WiFi not detected after installing updates for Ububtu12.04 LT on Dell inspiron 3537 laptop

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I installed reguralar Ubuntu 12.04LT updates through update manager. After installing updates it asked for system restart.I did the same and found that machine is not able to detect network (wireless as well as wired). Please help me.

Laptop is Dell-inspiron  3537 model.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same laptop with the same issue. The solution is very simple. Just follow the following steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Type the following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
   ```
3. Next type these commands

   ```
   wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
   tar xvf compat*
   cd compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc
   sudo su
   ./scripts/driver-select ath9k
   make
   make install
   modprobe ath9k
   exit
   ```
4. You are done...