# After the first update ubuntu 12.04 lost wireless alltogether

Tags: wireless

After the first update the Ubuntu 12.04 lost the wireless altogether. Even I have lost Enable wireless option display.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal. If an internal PCI device, run: lspci -nn | grep 0280. If USB, then: lsusb. Add the result to your question. Thanks.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)

Comment: Does it come to life if you do: sudo modprobe ath9k? Is the switch turned off? rfkill list all What is your kernel version? uname -r  Thanks.

Comment: ravikumar@ravikumar-Inspiron-3537:~$ sudo modprobe ath9k?
[sudo] password for ravikumar: 
FATAL: Module ath9k? not found.
ravikumar@ravikumar-Inspiron-3537:~$  rfkill list all 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
ravikumar@ravikumar-Inspiron-3537:~$ uname -r
3.5.0-49-generic
ravikumar@ravikumar-Inspiron-3537:~$

Comment: Now, local time 8am. Sorry for late reply. Due to late night(2-30am) I could not answer you.

Comment: The problem resolved. Refer page http://askubuntu.com/questions/409330/wireless-wifi-not-detected-after-installing-updates-for-ububtu12-04-lt-on-dell-i

Comment: That's one way to solve it, but not my preferred method since you have to recompile after every kernel update. I will give my suggestion in an answer that you may accept if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your device 168c:0036 is not covered in the default ath9k driver installed with Ubuntu 12.04. You can update the driver with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic
```

If you have installed the compat-wireless suite, you will probably need to remove it first:

```
cd ~/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc
sudo make uninstall
```